# Step through for Python loop with step size given in exponentials

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a Python list

```
q_s = [1E2,1E4,1E8,0]
```

I am trying to loop through values from `1E2` to `1E8` in steps of `1E4`. So, I need the loop values to be `1E2`+0*`1E4`, `1E2`+1*`1E4`, `1E2`+2*`1E4`, etc.

**Attempt with output:**

*Attempt:*

Here is my attempt:

```
for j in range(q_s[0],q_s[2],q_s[1]):
    print(j)
```

*Output:*

Here is the error message that it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    for q in range(q_s[0],q_s[2],q_s[1]):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

**Additional information:**

For the start, stop and step values, the start (`1E2`) and stop (`1E4`) values are realistic for what I am doing. The step value (`1E4`) is there just for testing purposes - in theory, I think that I should have freedom to use any value here - the code should not force me to pick certain step sizes for going through the `for` loop.

**Question:**

Is there a way to cycle through this loop using the start, stop and step sizes above?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are giving it a float and it expects an int. Make sure you are providing ints to range. That is all you have to do to get over that bug.

Comment: Yes, I should have just changed it from the beginning as you said. That's the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `xEy` in Python returns a `float`, not an `int`. `range` only handles `int`s.

The solution is to cast your values to `int`, like this:

```
for j in range(int(q_s[0]), int(q_s[2]), int(q_s[1])):
    print j
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
for i in [pow(2,j) for j in range(int(math.log(n,2)))]
```

n being the limit number

Example:

```
import math
for i in [pow(2,j) for j in range(int(math.log(64,2))+1)]:
    print(i)
```

Output:
1
2
4
8
16
32
64

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This looks promising, but if you could show some output with sample data, then that would be helpful.

Comment: Edited the comment, added example.